# Push full copy of my git repo to my remote

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, git-lfs

**Enviroment**

I converted my git repo using git-lfs-migrate and I am within a BARE Repo now. Everything seems fine: Converting finished without errors, tags are still available as well as branches. Those branches have a different commit id compared to before I converted. This id seems to be fine since `git show` prints some infos for the given id.

**Problem**

I push the my repo into a clean remote repo with `git push --mirror`. The log tells me that it pushed all my branches and Tags, but if I take a look at the remote repo (BitBucket UI) there are my tags but just my master branch.

**Question**

How can I push a full copy (containing all branches and tags) to my remote?

**What I've tried**

- I also created a local clone of my converted bare repo, but there
  excatly the same problem. Simply cloned with `git clone converted.git repo` and verified with `git branch -rv`
- Like already mentioned: The branches and it's ids seem to be valid
- `git push --all` does not help. After `git push --mirror` it just tells me that everything is up-to-date.

Git Version is 2.11.1 if that helps somehow!

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"... if I take a look at the remote repo ..."_ - what **specifically** are you looking at? What commands do you use?

Comment: I am using the web UI of Bitbucket. The combobox where I am able to select the branch only displays master to select.

Comment: It might be worth adding the bitbucket tag then, since it's not at all clear whether this is just a behaviour of that UI. If it defaults to showing only _local_ branches, for example, that would explain it (the branches you pushed will presumably be _remote_ in that repo). What's the relevance of git-lfs, by the way?

Comment: Didn't thought it depends on bitbucket since the local clone has the same problems but added it :) ty! Just added the git-lfs tag in case it has something to do with the converting (even if I don't think so). Sadly there's no git-lfs-migrate tag

Comment: oh, got it. If you explicitly push one of the missing branches (say _B_) with `git push bitbucket B:`, does it show up then?

Comment: Did you do `git clone --mirror` or just `git clone`?

Comment: @Useless hm does this work on bare repos? Hm I'll give it a try tomorrow! Ty! :) @Jim Redmond I did use `git clone --mirror` before I converted to get my bare repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s caused by the **converted repo doesn’t checkout all the remote branches locally**.

It seems it only has `master` branch as local branch (you can view the local brances by `git branch`), so in `.git/refs/heads`, you can only find `master`. And when you execute `git push --mirror <bitbucket repo URL>`, only the `master` branch (exist in `.git/refs`) will be push to the bitbucket repo.

So you should checkout all the remote branches locally (`git checkout branchname`) and then use `git push --mirror <bitbucket repo URL>` again.

Comment: The converted Repo shows all branches using `git branch -rv` and even says it pushes them all the the remote but the remote does not receive them

Comment: `git branch -rv` shows all the branches even they are not checkout locally. you should use `git branch` to view the local branch(es), and then use `git branch -a` to view all the remote branch, and then checkout other remote branches which were not checkout to locally.

Comment: Oh great! I am not very experienced in working with BARE Repos. Thought you can not have local branches there since there's no working dir but tried it right now. Your answer directly shows up what my mistake was in first place (see my answer to my question here :X). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok, you can mark the answer later. And it will also benefit others who have 

similar questions :)

Comment: I marked your answer because it shows up my mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I did a very stupid mistake at the very beginning of the process.
For sure I cloned my repository with `git clone --mirror` but I didn't think about where I am cloning from and that was a huge mistake. Instead of mirror cloning directly from bitbucket I mirror cloned my local working git which lead to that strange behaviour. It's still strange that after converting the Repo all branches are displayed by `git branch -rv` and even listed while doing a `git push --mirror` but I guess this was my fault.

Thanks for you all for trying to help me :) Really appreciate every single answer! Thanks again guys! And sorry!